# Sort vector by one value and the same values by other

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have vector of pointers to the objects. These objects have 2 properties, lets say: `int strenght` and `int age`. I want to sort this vector by `int strenght` but if there are same objects with the same `int strenght` then these obcjects should be sorted by `int age`. How can I do this in C++?

Comment: what did you try and how does it fail?

Comment: I tried to sort vector by age and after then by strenght. I used sort function from <algorithm>. The result looks fine but I don't know if I can be certain that the result will be always currect.